# js многоуровневые циклы

Tags: javascript

Прогаю на js уже около года, но как только вижу многоуровневые циклы сразу голова дымится. Как их удобнее понимать не напрягая мозг на 120%?)))

Comment: Обычно нужны очень веские причины, чтобы использовать больше 1 вложенного цикла

Comment: @iksuy, трехмерные массивы генерировали?)

Comment: На два вложенных для трехмерных массивов, да, чуть ли не единичный случай. Три вложенных для определенных научных расчетов могут применяться.

Answer (score 3):

Ну смотри: Скажем, у тебя есть объект с друзьями. И к каждому другу относится еще по несколько друзей. Задача состоит в том, что тебе нужно вывести пользователя и его друзей:

```
var user_friends = {
    Bob: ['July', 'John', 'Alex'],
    Alex: ['Bob', 'John'],
    July: ['Alex', 'Bob', 'John'],
    John: ['Bob', 'Alex', 'John']
};
```

Затем ты перебираешь объект в цикле:

```
for(var user in user_friends) {
    var friends = user_friends[user];
    //Переменная frieds на каждой итерации будет содержать массив с друзьями
}
```

Затем ты добавляешь в цикл еще один цикл, который будет перебирать массив с друзьями:

```
for(var user in user_friends) {
    //Тело первого цикла
    var friends = user_friends[user];
    var friends_string = '';

    for(var i=0; i<friends.length; i++) {
        //Тело второго цикла
        //Здесь на каждой итерации первого цикла
        //Будем перебирать массив fiends
        //И конкатинировать его в переменную:
        friends_string+=friends[i] + ' ,';

        //Здесь же выводим в консоль:

    }
  console.log('Friends', 'of', user, 'is', friends_string);
}
```

В принципе, все зависит от структуры, данных которые ты хочешь итерировать в циклах. Но нужно избегать многоуровневых циклов, - это достаточно ресурсоёмко.

Comment: какой-то не очень пример, внутренний цикл можно заменить `join(', ')`

Comment: @Grundy а с точки зрения реализации не то же самое будет?

Comment: @Risto, скорее всего нет. нативные операции над массивами могут быть оптимизированы. Ну и в коде из ответа добавляется лишняя запятая в конце

Comment: `for (var i in array)` надо использовать с надо использовать с условием `if (array.hasOwnProperty(i)){ ... }`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, в данном случае не надо, это только лишняя операция, а с массивами вообще `for..in` не рекомендуется использовать

Comment: Да можно использовать join(), дело в том что человек не понимает как реализуются вложенный циклы, только для понимания задачи я использовал данный пример

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас действительно такие сложные циклы, что трещит голова, и их нельзя избежать, делайте так:

- Берём внутренний цикл, смотрим, какие данные ему нужны для выполнения, выносим в функцию, с этими данными, в качестве аргументов.
- Заменяем в теле программы внутренний цикл на получившуюся функцию.
- Повторяем ту же операцию для родительского цикла, и так, пока не дойдём до цикла первого уровня.

Преимущества такого кода:

- Красота и понятность: вам не надо искать тот самый цикл, или выяснять, в каком цикле у вас та или иная строка кода, мучиться с отступами в пол строки, - все циклы в отдельных блоках-функциях.
- Отсутствие возни со счётчиками: Счётчики во всех циклах - локальные переменные, вам не надо обзывать их `i`, `j`, `k`, - называйте `i` и не мучайтесь. Если же внутренний цикл должен знать значение счётчика внешнего - передаёте его, как аргумент функции, обзывая по своему усмотрению.